# Take a string from user as a single command line argument, tokenize and display it

Tags: c, string, dynamic, command-line-interface

Take a string from the user as a single command line argument. Tokenize and store it in appropriate data structures and then display it.

I tried this code but it gives me a segmentation fault. I am unable to find out where it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define delim " "

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter only one argument as a single line string.\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    char *tmp1=NULL;
    int len=0;
    int count=0;
    int i=0;
    len=strlen(argv[1]);
    tmp1=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* (len)+1);

    if(NULL==tmp1)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failure single ptr.");
        exit (-1);
    }

    strcpy(tmp1,argv[1]);
    char *tok=NULL;
    char **data=NULL;
    tok=strtok(tmp1,delim);

    while(NULL!=tok)
    {
        count++;
        tok=strtok(NULL,delim);
    }

     strcpy(tmp1,argv[1]);

     data=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*count);
     if(NULL==data)
     {
         printf("Memory allocation failure double ptr.");
         exit (-1);
     }


     tok=strtok(tmp1,delim);
     while (NULL!=tok)
     {
         int l=strlen(tok);
         data[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*l)+1);
         if(NULL==data[i])
         {
             printf("Memory allocation failure ");
             exit (-1);
         }


         strcpy(data[i],tok);
         tok=strtok(NULL,delim);
         i++;
     }

     for (i=0; i<count; i++)
     {
         printf("%s\t",data[i]);
     }
     for (i=0; i<count; i++)
     {
         free(data[i]);
         data[i]=NULL;
     }
     data=NULL;

     free(tmp1);
     tmp1=NULL;
     return 0;
}
```

I passed "Hello this is the string" and it results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Apart from `data[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*l)+1);` this typo I do not see any issue here and ofcource you need to free `free(data)` before assigning it to `NULL` .

Comment: That could be an interesting typo if it compiled; it would lead to undefined behaviour as `data[i]` isn't a value returned by `malloc()`, so the freeing probably goes haywire, and there's overwriting beyond the end of the buffer too.

Comment: Please run your code in a debugger and pinpoint the instruction where the segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from running your code, you want to enter a string as argument and just parse it and print it, as simple as that right?

the code isn't compiling due to a typo in line:

```
data[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*l)+1);
```

After fixing it to:

```
data[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*l+1);
```

The output of the code is, for "hello this is string":

```
hello   this    is      string                                                                                                                           

...Program finished with exit code 0
```

If you still have segmentation error please post more information